# Bokeh Multichoice Onload Empty

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to implement a Bokeh multi-choice in my dashboard, and want to create a callback that starts the selection empty on the on-onload (I'm selecting from a large dataset and will want to user to be able to select only a few options).

I found the boilerplate code in the Bokeh documentation:

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, MultiChoice

OPTIONS = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]

multi_choice = MultiChoice(value=["foo", "baz"], options=OPTIONS)
multi_choice.js_on_change("value", CustomJS(code="""
    console.log('multi_choice: value=' + this.value, this.toString())
"""))

show(multi_choice)
```

How do I alter this code to make the selection begin empty?

Comment: remove `value=["foo", "baz"]`

Comment: or pass an empty list `value=[]`.